# Conditional formatting based on value of adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3UWG.png)

I have a bunch of information that I am trying to highlight based on the value of the information in the cell to the right of the current cell. I want it to be highlighted green if the value is greater than the value to the right, and red if lesser than the value to the right.

I have so far been unsuccessful. I tried a recommendation from another post that said "IF(B1<A1;1;0), but sadly, that did not work.

I hope you are able to help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple sample, you can refer it:

Select the Range or Cell you want to highlight- go to **Conditional Formatting**- Select **Manage Rule**- Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**- Enter the formula:

Greater than right: `=A1>B1` and format to **Green**

Less than right: `=A1<B1` and format to **Red**

[image]